# Can you animate individual origins of instances in geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, instances

Is there a way to tell geometry nodes to apply a different value to each instance? I have a file where I have a row of instanced rings. I want to apply a sine animation where each ring is slightly offset in the timing. I've included the file to the point as I understand what's going on.

[image]

[image]

Apologies in advance, I'm new to geometry nodes and math isn't my strong suit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can do that, here is the node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

the value has the same driver, as you had: #frame/12

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I was originally using a position node instead of an index node (and obviously some of my workflow was in the wrong order). I will just have to keep on practicing and reading up on all the nodes.

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 4):

> The cool thing about this solution is that the circles/instances maintain their distance from each other.

Here's a more advanced design, where you don't just move the positions of the circles, but where a precise chaining of circles is created.

[image: Animation]

Each circle is strung together like a chain link, giving you a nice chain.

I achieve the animation here by changing the angle between the circles with a sine curve.

Both the radius (can also be a random radius) of the circles and the amplitude and the speed of the wave are made flexible in this example.

[image: Node Tree]

This answer is essentially based on an answer given earlier: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258788/145249.

The structure here is almost identical, up to also the generation of the angles, which runs off here evenly time-controlled.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the write up! Geometry nodes are so useful and powerful, but getting the hang of the math is a little overwhelming. I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: I understand what you mean ;-) ...but take heart, it sometimes looks a little overwhelming at first glance, but with a little trial and error and reading through it several times, it gets easier and eventually you hardly notice it anymore.